# Shopify Search Box isn't working properly

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

We have a website built in Shopify platform, we are getting the problem with a search box. If I enter any query or keywords in the search box, the search result comes with lost of content which has a similar word on the pages.

For example, If I search "contact us" in the search box, the result looks like this. Click on the below link. Can anyone tell us how can we avoid showing such results on the website.

[image: webpage screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

If you blur out your demonstration info, how is anyone supposed to help you?

The one thing you did not blur out, the product MaxFlex probably has the word contact or us in the description or in some place. Hence it is shown by Shopify search results. You can always inspect and modify your search results yourself since you get that as a Liquid template. If you feel you want to alter the results, make some modifications to that template.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Nope. You are on your own now. When you can edit search results via liquid, you are the boss. You cannot control the actual results from Shopify unless you totally replace their search with your own. Some people do that. It is a large undertaking.